# Why is ((MainActivity) getActivity()) giving me a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Helo,

I've got the following code:

EventPopup.java

```
class EventPopup extends Dialog {

private boolean delete;
private boolean edit;
private boolean editall;

private ReadEvent event;
```

...
    }

DayFragment.java (this is a fragment)

```
final EventPopup eventpopup = new EventPopup(getContext(), readevent);

            eventpopup.show();

            eventpopup.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {

                    if(eventpopup.getDelete()) {
                        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).refreshViewPager();
                    } else if (eventpopup.getEdit()) {
                        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).doEditEvent(readevent, eventpopup.getEditAll());
                    }
                }
            });
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public void refreshViewPager() {
    doubleViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Why this line gives sometimes NullPointerException on some devices (on others not)?:

```
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).refreshViewPager();
```

The error message is:

> java.lang.NullPointerException:
>
> at de.ubik.terminkalender.DayFragment$8$1.onDismiss (DayFragment.java:1378)
>
> at android.app.Dialog$ListenersHandler.handleMessage (Dialog.java:1749)
>
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
>
> at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6692)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1468)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1358)

I've got the following structure: MainActivity (with viewpager) -> DayFragment (as a Fragment) -> Dialog. When I close the dialog I want to check if there is a button clicked in the dialog. When clicked, then refresh viewpager in MainActivity. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

`onDismiss`.

That means your dialog was dismissed which detaches itself from your Activity which means `getActivity()` will return null.  It's best to find another way to refresh the viewpager.  How you do this is dependent on why you're refreshing.

Comment: I've got the following structure: MainActivity (with viewpager) -> DayFragment (as a Fragment) -> Dialog. When I close the dialog I want to check if there is a button clicked in the dialog. When clicked, then refresh viewpager in MainActivity. How to achieve that?

Comment: Rather than have a "refreshViewpager" callback, have a "buttonClicked" callback. The dialog will tell the Activity that the button was clicked. Then the Activity will dismiss the dialog and refresh itself.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by @Deev you will always get a null and the solution for this is that call your Dialog from some of the method which has getActivity as a parameter.

sample code:

```
 //call this from your fragment 
 showDialog(getActivity());
```

and in your fragment place this somewhere

```
public void showDialog(final Activity activity){
    final EventPopup eventpopup = new EventPopup(activity, readevent);
        eventpopup.show();
        eventpopup.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {

                if(eventpopup.getDelete()) {
                    ((MainActivity)activity).refreshViewPager();
                } else if (eventpopup.getEdit()) {
                    ((MainActivity) activity).doEditEvent(readevent, eventpopup.getEditAll());
                }
            }
        });
}
```

this will work for sure.

Comment: Ok, i will try that